# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to resolve Error CS0103 The name 'score' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core 6, I have this code.

```
public static class Paginator
{
    public static async Task<PageResult<IEnumerable<TDestination>>> PaginationAsync<TSource, TDestination>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, int pageSize, int pageNumber, IMapper mapper)
        where TSource : class
        where TDestination : class
    {
        var count = queryable.Count();

        var pageResult = new PageResult<IEnumerable<TDestination>>
        {
            PageSize = (pageSize > 10 || pageSize < 1) ? 10 : pageSize,
            CurrentPage = pageNumber > 1 ? pageNumber : 1,
            TotalRecord = count,
            PreviousPage = pageNumber > 0 ? pageNumber - 1 : 0
        };

        pageResult.NumberOfPages = count % pageResult.PageSize != 0
                ? count / pageResult.PageSize + 1
                : count / pageResult.PageSize;

        var sourceList = await queryable.Skip((pageResult.CurrentPage - 1) * pageResult.PageSize).Take(pageResult.PageSize).ToListAsync();

        var destinationList = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TDestination>>(sourceList);
        pageResult.PageItems = destinationList;

        return pageResult;
    }
}
```

Repository interface:

```
IQueryable<Score> GetExamScoreAsync(PagingFilter filter)
```

Repository implementation:

```
public IQueryable<Score> GetExamScoreAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
    var examScores = _dbContext.Scores
            .Where(m => (bool)m.Approval.IsFirstLevel == false)
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery)
        || x.Subject.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower())
        || x.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
    return examScores;
}
```

Then I called it it the service:

```
public async Task<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<ScoreListDto>>>> GetScoreAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
    var userName = _currentUserService.UserName;
    var getUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    var loggedUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(getUser);
    var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString();

    if (loggedUserRoleName == "Student")
    {
        var score = await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreStudentAsync(filter);
    }
    else
    {
        var score = await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreAsync(filter);
    }
        
    var item = await score.PaginationAsync<Score, ScoreListDto>(filter.PageSize, filter.PageNumber, _mapper);

    return new Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<ScoreListDto>>>()
    {
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Successful = true,
        Data = item
    };
}
```

I got this error:

> Error CS0103 The name 'score' does not exist in the current context

Score is highlighted in:

```
var item = await score.PaginationAsync<Score, ScoreListDto>(filter.PageSize, filter.PageNumber, _mapper);
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each block where you define `var score` (between the `if {}` and the `else{}`) determines the scope of the variable.  In Javascript, which you might be more used to, the scope of a `var` is "hoisted" to the top-level of a function.  This is not so in C#.  You have to declare the variable within the scope where you're going to use it. So, you'll have to define it before the `if` statement so that it's available at the point where you call `score.PaginationAsync` call.  Something like this:

```cs
    MyScoreType score;
    if (loggedUserRoleName == "Student")
    {
        score = await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreStudentAsync(filter);
    }
    else
    {
        score = await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreAsync(filter);
    }
```

An alternative approach would be to inline the if statement like this:

```cs
var score = (loggedUserRoleName == "Student")
    ? await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreStudentAsync(filter)
    : (loggedUserRoleName == "Teacher")
        ? await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreTeacherAsync(filter)
        : await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreAsync(filter);
```

Comment: Thanks. But what will MyScoreType be?

Comment: @Ayobamilaye Take a look at the definition for `PaginationAsync()` it will probably be in a .cs file that looks like `class MyScoreType` - you use the name of the class.

Comment: I have updated my post with PaginationAsync(). Kindly allow me to ask again, what will I declare as?

Comment: The alternative methed may not work, because I am adding elseif loggedUserRoleName == "Teacher"           _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreTeacherAsync(filter)

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the 'score' variable within the if-else statement, so it's scope only remains in the if-else statement. Just declare it before the if statement and it should be accessible.

```
var score = new Score(); //Assuming Score is the data type your varaiable has
if (loggedUserRoleName == "Student")
{
    score = await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreStudentAsync(filter);
}
else
{
    score = await _unitOfWork.ExamScore.GetExamScoreAsync(filter);
}
```

Comment: when I did var score, I got this error:  
Error CS0818 Implicitly-typed variables must be initialized.

Comment: @Ayobamilaye see my answer where you should insert _your variable type_ instead of `var` in this case.

Comment: @Ayobamilaye My bad I edited my answer. You can follow Bron's solution or if you really want to use a var data type then initialize it first as: var score = new Score().

Comment: it looks like it would be `PageResult<IEnumerable<ScoreListDto>>`  I also added to my answer an alternative approach.

Comment: @BronDavies - In the alternative method, why am I getting this tooltip   Unncessary assignment of a value to 'score'  on   var score = (loggedUserRoleName == "Student")

Comment: You won't need `PageResult<IEnumerable<ScoreListDto>> score;` with the alternative method.